# Startup problems with desktop, indicator light not blinking, no error on monitor, blank screen

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I'm having this erratic behaviour with my new PC.

CPU/Processor: Intel i5-8400
Memory: DDR4 16 GIGS Kingston Hyper X Furry
Video Card : NONE
Operating System: Windows 10 64 bit
Hard Drive: Samsung EVO 860 250GB

Problems are with restarts, but also used to be some "check disk" on restarts. So I bought a new SSD Samsung EVO, 2 days old.

Now the PC still has the same problem. Here are the symptoms:

- Can't turn on, PC has 2 lights , on blue power on and one flashing red light indicator. The blue one turns on , but the flashing red light doesn't
- Sometimes, I hold the button down on restart for 10 seconds, blue light comes on, then shuts off by itself, then comes on again, red light not flashing
- Turn the pc on as usual, on short press of power button, stays on for 5 seconds, turns off, then back on again by itself, no red light flashing

What I have done:

- Reset CMOS and upgraded BIOS
- Changed RAM slot
- Tested a multitude of SSD and HDD
- Unplugged everything
- Did a mdsched.exe on RAM (OK)

Something that is quite strange...even if I take all the disks out, still nothing, I should at least get a blinking white text on black screen saying "No disk found" right?

I tried to reformat with DVD, but I can't even get in F2 to set up boot sequence.

What could this be?

Comment: If its new claim on the warranty. If its a self build take it to a repair shop where they will have more testing/diagnostic capability ...

Comment: Problem is I'm in Thailand, the techs are incompetent and no English...they might make it even worse or miss diagnose...say it's the motherboard, wait 4 weeks, not the problem, say it's the CPU, wait 4 weeks, not the problem, say it's the PSU, wait 4 weeks, not the problem etc...no PC for months! ;(